# random texture placement in material, based on frame

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I have a puzzle... 100 shapes with 4 separate textures that apply to each polygon.
I want to have the 4 textures cycle in a random manner based on the frame number.
with the option to change the frequency of change...
1 per frame
2 frames then change ( on 2's as explained in animation terms)
3 frames then change
4 frames then change
on through to 8

its important that the 100 polygon puzzle shapes all change the texture randomly of each other.

in my mind I figure it could be done in either the material nodes or the animation nodes.
I would like to use the animation nodes if possible.

Comment: Could you provide some illustrations (steps) of the animation and an example of the textures?

Comment: I have a file and illustrations on blender artist... here is the link...

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/random-textures-based-on-frame/1254177/5?u=fleabilly

Comment: How can I create an variable event...
**Every Frame**
**every 2nd frame**... (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21...)  
**every 4th frame**... (1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29...  
**every 6th frame**... (1,7,13,19,25,31...)  
**every 8th frame**... (1,9,17,25,33...)  
  
The Event would be-randomly cycling between 4 image texture nodes.  
  
could I also make the random event trigger a new random frame advance, based on the 5 random frame sequences listed above.